# BlueZ, do not require authentication

Tags: bluetooth, obex, bluez

I'm working with `BlueZ 3.x.` I have a linux embedded device and I need to send and receive files using the bluetooth technology, with `Obex`. (Note: `BlueZ 4.x` doesn't even compile on our specific platform.)

I don't need PIN authentication, I even don't want it. It must remain as simple as possible for the end user.

I tried to set `security none` in `hcid.conf` but it doesn't seem to work.

So my question is:

1. Is it possible to send &/ receive files using Obex on bluetooth?
2. How to do it?
3. Does bluetooth devices (e.g. mobile phone) requires authentication?

Comment: I've read that some phones ask for a PIN Code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the OBEX protocoll for that, but you will also need the FTP or OPP profile (And GOEP, SPP & GAP since they depend on them)
2. The documentation can be found on BT SIG bluetooth.org, but you will have to be a member. I think some of the documentation is available to non members as well, go there and have a look.
3. Yes (if we are only talking about mobile phones)